# How to clear messages in IBM MQ which are stuck for more than 5 mins?

Tags: ibm-mq

I don't want to use message expiry as it has dependency on sending application and don't want to use pub/sub as well because if the applications don't take the messages it will fill up the filesystem etc.  I don't want the messages to be piled up in the queue because application is down.

This setup is required so that there wont be any outage because of this queue and the application consuming it.  Any advice?

Comment: FYI: In pub/sub, if there are no subscribers for a topic, then the published message on that topic will be discarded. Not written to file system except where a publication is a RETAIN_PUBLICATION and persistent. So you can use a non-durable subscriber that will consume messages as long it is running.

Answer (score 4):

CAPEXPRY allows the administrator to set message expiry without application changes. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097495_.htm